# how to change DataGridView column type into Button?

Tags: c#, datagridview

i am populating data from MySQL table into datagridview using dataset i have 5 column which are automatic generating by dataset , i want change programmatically column[4] EditText type into Button type ?
trying this but incomplete syntax

```
grid2.Columns[4].CellType = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must first create this column with type you need then add it to grid. But i don't remember without book.

```
    CheckBoxField col = new CheckBoxField();
    gvQuestions.Columns.Add((DataControlField)col);
```